# How to retrieve specific JSON objects only from a nested JSON

Tags: json, jackson, gson

I have a nested JSON structure. I want to retrieve only a particular branch of the structure and ignore the rest of the objects in the JSON.

For example, given:

```json
{
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop2": {
    "child": "childval"
  },
  "prop3": {
    "child": "childval"
  }
}
```

Here, I want to retrieve only `prop3` along with `prop1` ignoring `prop2`.

```json
{
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop3": {
    "child": "childval"
  }
}
```

Would it require the usage of Jackson libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Java library for JSON (de)serialization should be able to handle this, but here is how you can achieve it using Jackson:

```java
    // Required imports

    public static String removeProps(String json, List<String> propertiesToRemove) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);

        propertiesToRemove.forEach(prop -> removeProp(rootNode, prop));

        return rootNode.toString();
    }

    public static void removeProp(JsonNode node, String prop) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
            if (objectNode.has(prop)) {
                objectNode.remove(prop);
            } else {
                objectNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> removeProp(entry.getValue(), prop));
            }
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            node.elements().forEachRemaining(element -> removeProp(element, prop));
        }
    }
```

```
// Example usage
String json = "{\"prop1\":\"val1\",\"prop2\":{\"child\":\"childval\"},\"prop3\":{\"child\":\"childval\"}}";

List<String> propsToRemove = List.of("prop2");
String jsonWithoutProps = removeProps(json, propsToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson, it will deserialize only the stuff you define.
Here is some code (that uses lombok for the getters and setters).
First define classes that represent the JSON structure.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Prop3
{
  private String child;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Blammy
{
  private String prop1;
  private Prop3 prop3;
}
```

Here is code to deserialize the JSON from a String.

```
Blammy blammy;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

blammy = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Blammy.class);
```

Comment: In my case, I do not know the key value pairs coming in. It is not a definite set

Comment: If you don't know the key-value pairs that are being sent to you, then you can't know which key-value pairs you want to process.  Perhaps you left out some details in the description of the problem.